# iam trying to send data from angular services to nodejs backend Nothing happens

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, http

I have enclosed my service function here. Iam trying to send a simple data to node backend but nothing happens. But at this API Endpoint the things works well its saving data in good shape(in postman). Iam sure iam wrong somewhere here in angular No Errors are triggering. **No http request is raised**.

```
App.service('UserServices', function($rootScope, $http) {
  this.AddToInviteList = function(email, cb) {
    var url = $rootScope.api_server_url + "/users/addtoinvitelist";
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log("email is posted sucessfully" + data);
      cb(data);
    })
  }
})
```

and my controller code is here,

```
App.controller('InviteController', function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, UserServices) {
  $scope.AddToInviteList = function(email) {
    UserServices.AddToInviteList(email, function(dataresponse) {
      console.log(dataresponse);
    })
  }
});
```

And my HTML View div is below.

```
    <div class="tab-content">

        <!--NEWSLETTER FORM-->
                                <div class="panel panel-minimalize">
                                    <h2 class="signin-brand animated-hue"> <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> MEDICOSHERE</h2>
                                    <div class="panel-body bg-inverse ui-corner-all">
                                        <form action="#">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="subcribeNewsletter" class="control-label">INVITE FORM<br> <small>We are happy to invite you to medicoshere, So please enter your email ID in the below form.</small></label>
                                                <div class="input-group input-group-in input-group-sm">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope text-belpet"></i></div>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="subcribeNewsletter" placeholder="johndoe@mail.com" ng-model="email" required>
                                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-belpet" ng-click="AddToInviteList(email)"><strong>OK</strong></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                        </form><!-- /form -->
                                    </div><!-- /.panel-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.panel -->
                                <!--/END NEWSLETTER FORM-->
                            </div><!-- /.cols -->

</main>
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? What about the console log at the controller response?

Comment: Nothing happens...no logs and no errors at browser console.... So basic error triggered i sort it out then no error and no logs

Answer (score 0):

Will it would be nice to have a bit more of information regarding your problem but I already see some potential issues.

First of all I hope that App variable (App.service) is an instance of your angular's main module.

Also, I believe you must return the function in an object at the begging or end of your service declaration. That way it'll work as expected when calling it from your controller.

So I believe it should look something like this:

```
var App = angular.module('myApp');
App.service('UserServices', function($rootScope, $http) {
 this.AddToInviteList = function(email, cb) { 
       var url = $rootScope.api_server_url + "/users/addtoinvitelist"; 
       $http({ 
           method: 'POST', 
           url: url,
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded '
        } 
    // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload) })
    .success(function(data) { 
          console.log("email is posted sucessfully" + data); 
          cb(data);
   }) 
}

  return {
         AddToInviteList:AddToInviteList
   }
})
```

Sorry for the bad indentation :) writing from a smartphone.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Also, are you sure you added the file to your index.html? :D

**Another thing to check**

You might want to check in your routing is OK. Perhaps you're not associating that view to the right controller. That or not including the service file could be one of the reasons you're not getting any errors.

Comment: i had associated to the controller. I checked that return thing but yet it dint work for me.....I have added the js files also..

Comment: I also just realized you are declaring the service with 2 parameters, but only passing one (email) when calling it in your controller. Is the service on a separate file? Are you including it? Could you console log the service to see if an instance of the service object is returned? ( In your controller)

Comment: Good to know! I'm glad I was helpful. If you found my answer complete and necessary to solve your issue, please mark as accepted answer! Thanks! That's so when other people see this question, they'll know where you get your response from :D